# VLC does not play live SAT TV stream

Tags: udp, vlc, rtsp, rtp, live-streaming

I m trying to play live input multicast streaming from SAT TV on my fedora PC with VLC player. By using below command from terminal, it launches VLC player and plays **audio** but does not play **video**. Terminal prints below errors repeatably.

**vlc -vvv rtp://@239.192.xx.xx:52xxx**

```
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xbe:1b:7b:02] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x95:9e:7c:e5] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x4b:4c:bc:c7] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xbc:96:c9:48] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x0a:60:c3:0d] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xcd:d7:b0:e8] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xa4:67:c4:34] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xbf:6e:5f:46] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x96:5b:69:a6] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xf9:c3:83:a9] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xf9:f5:54:e6] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x62:67:49:c5] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: scrambled state changed on pid 2048 (0->1)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x47:ba:02:20] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xe8:f4:4f:04] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x40:4e:26:f6] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xe5:d6:e2:69] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x1c:26:63:58] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xbb:24:63:98] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x6c:6f:55:39] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xc0:5a:32:53] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: scrambled state changed on pid 2048 (1->0)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: scrambled state changed on pid 2048 (0->1)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0x9a:26:4a:56] (pid: 2048)
[084161a0] ts demux warning: invalid header [0xd8:48:bd:87] (pid: 2048)
```

In VLC->tools->Media Info-> Statistics tab has details about Audio packets but Video has non.

Do I have to enable some setting on the VLC to display video or is it unable to decode the input stream packets? Should I be using different player ?

Can some one please provide some pointers.

Appreciate any help on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scramble state flag tells me this content is protected. It will most likely not be playable without a decryption key/system.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a way to work around ?